# How to use script tag with src in ionic script templates?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

How to use script tag with src in ionic script templates ??

i want to use livescore script src from another website in my app but script doesnt work in script templates

```
  <script id="templates/match.html" type="text/ng-template">
     <script src='http://**'></script>
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to know too, currently im using this,

```
$scope.$on("$ionicView.loaded", function () {
    console.log($state);
    document.onclick = function (e) {
        e = e ||  window.event;
        var element = e.target || e.srcElement;

        if (element.tagName == 'A') {
            window.open(element.href, "_system", "location=yes");
            return false; // prevent default action and stop event propagation
        }
    };
});
```

In my controller but once this is injected every view gets affected. I only want that to happen to certain views and not the whole app.